# Format plural problems in Views module

Tags: views, comments

I built a Drupal 7 site using the Views module and I am using the "comment count" field.

If I choose the format plural checkbox, with a comment, it will output "1 comment", and when there are zero comments, 2 or more comments, it will output the number of comments followed by *comments*. If I want to output "no comments yet" when the comment count is 0, I can use the "No result  behavior (Count the number 0 as empty)" option.

The problem is that the format plural option is not working together with the "No result  behavior" option. When I use both of them, I get "0 comments" instead of "no comments yet."

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using the following settings for the **Content: Comment count** field:

- **Format plural** checked
- **Singular form**: @count *comment*
- **Plural form**: @count *comments*

Under **No results behavior**:

- **No result text**: *no comments yet*
- **Count the number 0 as empty** checked
- **Hide if empty**  checked
- **Hide rewriting if empty** checked

Comment: See also the issue [Prefix causes empty on 0 fields to not be empty](https://www.drupal.org/node/1239522) where the solution is a third value in format plural to have a "Zero form".